# Get Key From Multidimensional Index

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array structure:

```
$CATEGORIES = array(
    array(
        category => "music", 
        color => "#FF8800"
        ),
     array(
        category => "film & TV", 
        color => "#59AF56"
        ),
    array(
        category => "culture", 
        color => "#fc2525"
        ),
    array(
        category => "science/tech", 
        color => "#5da9d4"
        )
    );
```

Basically, the category will be looked up and I need to retrieve the hex value. I can't find anything that will do this for a multidimensional array (after trying with array_search() ). Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why dont you just make a foreach over it and and test with an if the category when found return the hex?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$category = 'culture';
foreach($CATEGORIES as $key){
   if($key['category'] == $category)
      $hex = $key['color'];//here is your color
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/ZRpBtwjK)

Comment: How would I then just select the hex  that matches the category?

Comment: What is the condition that you want? hex what would be to select it?

Comment: - There will be the category already stored in variable $category.
- Look up array, check which index contains category = $category
- Find color value of that array

Comment: edit my answer is what you need? @DorianHuxley